# How do you subset a dataframe based on values from a list?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I want to return a new dataframe only including those rows that exist in a a new dataframe I created. When indexing would you do something like %in% or can you have a dataframe or convert into vector inside the brackets?

Comment: Please put an [mre] in your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to get a  better info on your problem with an example, but there are a few ways to extract a data frame from specific rows.

One basic way is:
`new.data <- data[0:100, ]`  <-This method only takes the rows you specify, in this case the first 100 rows, but it is based on the position of the rows and not their value.

Another way is using `dplyr::filter`, if you want to subtract rows based on their value. For example:

```
data$variableX=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
new.data <- filter(data, variableX==c(1,2,3))
```

Read up on the `dplyr filter` function for more info and good luck